# Propel installation on local server

Tags: php, propel

I Want to install the propel in my windows local server,I was looking at the guide but am not sure how to run their commands.any one can explain me how should i proceed with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their instructions boil down to:

1. Go to whatever the owner project is and create a folder called vendor. Or go to some other folder if your project doesn't use that convention.
2. Put the source code in that folder.

TA-DA! Propel is installed. ;-)

If you'd like to use Propel's command line tools, it will take a bit more work.

If you're using WAMP you might be able to find pear by running `<drive>:\wamp\bin\php\php<version>\go-pear.bat`, but that isn't always consistent.
XAMPP has pear available by default at `<drive>:\xampp\php\pear.bat`

Once you've found `pear`, then either cd to the directory or call `path\to\pear.bat` channel-discover pear.phing.info (replace channel... with all of the other pear commands)

For your purposes this line: `ln -s vendor/propel/generator/bin/propel-gen propel-gen` should be "Make a Windows shortcut to vendor/propel/generator/bin/propel-gen called propel-gen and place it in your project folder"

Comment: I am using wamp server ,I ran the c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\go-pear.bato-pear.bat and it opened the command prompt but when i tried to enter i got that window closed,please advice

Comment: Run it from the command line. Hit Windows key + r, type "CMD" and press enter. CD c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\